# why is mod_rewrite facility working?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to do simple rewriting url with using mod_rewrite facility of Apache. 
As they said i firstly remove the # from the

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

from conf. file. then i restart my apache.
now what i want is something like this...

on my index page there is one menu in which their is one link of "aboutus" like this..

```
<a href="aboutus"><strong>about</strong></a>
```

now in my htaccessfile, i had written something like this...

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^aboutus$ tempindex.php?id=3
</IfModule>
```

and if i tried to click on the aboutus then its shows **error HTTP 404 - Not Found.**

**EDIT:**
I am trying to make my url as

```
www.example.com/aboutus
```

but actual the url will be

```
www.example.com/tempindex.php?id=3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [rewrite log and rewrite log level directives](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) in your httpd.conf to get Apache to tell you all about the matches it makes (or doesn't).